# How to set up efficient build when working with nodeJS and Angular 6 app development

Tags: node.js, angular, build

I am working on an application using express to serve Angular 6 front-end. However each time I write some code and want to test, I have to run

`ng build && cd path/to/dist && node server.js`

This makes development very slow.

`ng serve` on the other hand is obviously very fast. Is there a way I can make ng build faster?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using two servers. One development server for Angular and another one for express

Comment: @matejko219 I also wish to run 2 servers but there is restriction to only run one application instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--watch` flag with `ng build` to have it automatically re-run the build whenever a file changes. Since this only rebuilds the modules that the change affects, this is generally much faster than a full `ng build`.

Assuming your node server is just serving the files from the location (and isn't doing some bizarre caching), this will result in your changes being available after a refresh

---

**TLDR**

```
ng build --watch
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is what I needed! Thanks.